# SQL order by not allowed in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get top 30 players who played the game most. However, I can't seem to retrieve from sorted subquery.

```
select top 30 percent * 
from 
    (select username, count(*) as c 
     from plays 
     group by username
     order by username desc) t
```

without the order by, the `top 30 percent` will only reflect the first 30 percent of the output. So how can I get it sorted?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please update your question with sample data & table definitions along with the exact error message (or unexpected output) that you receive when executing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 issues with the query you tried:

- If you want to sort descending by number of plays, do so; don't sort by `username`...
- Simply put the `order by` outside the subquery clause: give `count(*)` an alias via `count(*) as n_plays` and then sort the outer query `order by n_plays desc`. Aliases declared in the `select` list are available in the `order by` clause, so no subquery (or CTE or whatever) is necessary.
- If you want the top 30 *players*, then that's not the top 30 *`percent`*, is it? so just isolate the `top 30 *`, no `percent`.

---

So, let's put it all together:

```sql
select top 30
  username,
  count(*) as n_plays
from plays
group by username
order by n_plays desc;
```

where the data was created by:

```sql
create table plays (
  id int identity not null primary key,
  username varchar(100)
  -- other fields like date/time, comment, etc.
);

declare @i int = 1;

while @i <= 1000
begin
  insert into plays (username)
  values ( 'Player' + cast( cast(rand() * 99 as int) as varchar) );
  
  set @i += 1;
end;
```

---

working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/aebdf/4

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the order by to outside the subquery and you should be ordering by c to capture the top 30%.

Try this..

```
select top 30 percent * 
from 
    (select username, count(*) as c 
     from plays 
     group by username
     ) t
order by c desc
```

In your question you mention getting the top 30 results, if this is the case remove "percent" from the query.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a subquery:

```
select top 30 percent username, count(*) as c 
from plays 
group by username
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score -1):

For the top 30 you could do this?

```
select username, count(*) as c 
     from plays 
     group by username
     order by c desc
     LIMIT 30
```

Comment: `limit` is not available in SQL Server.