# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS when retrieve data from another table

Tags: sql

following this: [SQL order by not allowed in subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62519470/sql-order-by-not-allowed-in-subquery/62520781#62520781)

Now I want to retrieve `userid` and `username` from a user table. This is what I did:

```
select * from user where user.username in (select top 30
  username,
  count(*) as n_plays
from plays
group by username
order by n_plays desc)
```

Why do I get the error?

Comment: please tag with database platform, and the error

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are getting *that* error.  You have an `in` subquery that should return one column but is returning two.  An alternative uses `join`:

```
select u.*
from user u join
     (select top 30 username, count(*) as n_plays
      from plays p
      group by p.username
      order by count(*) desc
     ) pu
     on pu.username = u.username;
```